# Can read correctly a CSV file

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv

I have an issue with a CSV file reading, I can't parse it correctly. I think it's come from file format but I'm not sure

I retreive the file from an FTP connexion

```js
await client.downloadTo('.cache/temp.csv', lastFile.name);
const csv = await this.readCsvFile('.cache/temp.csv');
```

And parse it with a function

```js
async readCsvFile(filePath: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const results = [];
      fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'utf-8' })
        .pipe(csvParser())
        .on('data', (data) => {
          results.push(data);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          resolve(results);
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

If I console.log the results variable, I obtain a sample like this

```
{
    'Identifiants;Type de formulaire;Entr�e;Date auto;Heure auto;R�serve Txt;R�serve num;Num�rique pour entr�e internet avec questionnaire SAT;Num�rique pour entr�e restaurant avec questionnaire SAT;Affichage sommaire;{Mode contact};{Ch�re(e) client(e)': '07E703010D251F02DC;GRC;;01/03/2023;13:37:33;;;       0;       0;       0;;Autre chose;Oui;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;       0;       0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;;;;;;       0;       0;       0;       0;;;;       0;       0;       1;       1;;Internet;;FRA;;service.consommateurs@redacted.fr;service.consommateurs@redacted.fr;France;;;;;       1;Ouvert;;;       0;;'
  },
  {
    'Identifiants;Type de formulaire;Entr�e;Date auto;Heure auto;R�serve Txt;R�serve num;Num�rique pour entr�e internet avec questionnaire SAT;Num�rique pour entr�e restaurant avec questionnaire SAT;Affichage sommaire;{Mode contact};{Ch�re(e) client(e)': '07E703010C24211179;GRC;;01/03/2023;13:37:34;;;       0;       0;       0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;       0;       0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;       0;;;;;;       0;       0;       0;       0;;;;       0;       0;       0;       0;;;;FRA;;;;;;;;;       1;Ouvert;;;       0;;'
  },
```

with unknown characters and without parsing (I have tried multiple encodings such as utf-8 but no changes)

Comment: Have you tried `{ encoding: 'ISO-8859-1' }` instead?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  ISO-8859-1 is not compatible with variable encoding

Comment: Looks like your CSV has `;` as separator instead of comma. Maybe there's a way to configure your `csvParser` to use this separator

Comment: @NikitaIvanov that solve my first problem yes thanks

Comment: As for encoding, maybe the file itself has broken characters, or these characters cannot be displayed by your terminal? I suggest you to try and open the file with some text editor with automatic encoding recognition and see what it says about possible encoding of the file